# Conditional statements in xsl

Tags: xslt

I working on a site which some if/or statements in XSL and being a little unfamilar with the language i'm not certain how to accomplish:

if [condion one is met] or [condition two is met] then do [action] otherwise do [alternative action]

can anyone offer some examples?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Conditionals in XSLT are either an unary "if":

```
<xsl:if test="some Boolean condition">
  <!-- "if" stuff (there is no "else" here) -->
</xsl:if>
```

or more like the switch statement of other languages:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="some Boolean condition">
    <!-- "if" stuff -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- "else" stuff -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

where there is room for as many `<xsl:when>`s as you like.

Every XPath expression can be evaluated as a Boolean [according to a set of rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-Boolean-Functions). These (for the most part) boil down to "if there is something -> `true`" / "if there is nothing -> `false`"

- the empty string is `false`
- 0 is `false` (so is `NaN`)
- the empty node set is `false`
- the result of `false()` is `false`
- every other literal value is `true` (most notably: `'false'` is `true` and `'0'` is `true`)
- the result of expressions is evaluated with said rules (no surprise here)

---

Edit: There is of course a more advanced (and more idiomatic) method to control program flow, and that's template matching:

```
<xsl:template match="node[contains(., 'some text')]">
  <!-- output X -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node[not(contains(., 'some text'))]">
  <!-- output Y -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//node" />
</xsl:template>
```

Writing templates that match specific nodes and using `<xsl:apply-templates>` to make the XSLT processor choose the appropriate ones is superior to writing complex `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>` constructs.

The above sample is equivalent to the imperative style:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=".//node">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(., 'some text')">
        <!-- output X -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains(., 'some text'))">
        <!-- output Y -->
      </xsl:when>
    <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT beginners tend to pick the latter form for its familiarity, but examining template matching instead of using conditionals is worthwhile. (also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478045/18771).)

Comment: If I understand you correctly I should be applying a dual test in boolean <xsl:if test="string-length($name) &gt; 0 or string-length($nameTwo) &gt; 0"> or should I be using multiple when/otherwise sets?

Comment: It depends. If you wanted to check if *any* of the strings is not empty, you could also do: <xsl:if test="concat($name, $nameTwo) != ''">

Comment: Hi, what would an example condition look like? ie: <xsl:if test="var = 1"> ?

Answer (score 4):

XSL has an `<xsl:if>`, but you're probably looking more for a `<xsl:choose>` / `<xsl:when>` / `<xsl:otherwise>` sequence.  Some examples [here](http://www.learn-xslt-tutorial.com/Flow-Control.cfm) (near the bottom).  Maybe:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="[conditionOne] or [conditionTwo]">
        <!-- do [action] -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- do [alternative action] -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

The general if statement syntax is

```
<xsl:if test="expression">
  ...some output if the expression is true...
</xsl:if>
```

Not sure if XSL has the else condition but you should be able to test if true then test if false or the other way around.

Comment: You're right about the `else`; XSL has `<xsl:otherwise>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would have to use a `xsl:choose`. It's like using if/else with a final else.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="condition one or condition two">
    <!-- action -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- alternative action -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```