# What are the differences between 'call-template' and 'apply-templates' in XSL?

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

I am new in XSLT so I'm little bit confused about the two tags,

```
<xsl:apply-templates name="nodes">
```

and

```
<xsl:call-template select="nodes">
```

So can you list out the difference between them?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

`<xsl:call-template>` is a close equivalent to calling a function in a traditional programming language.

You can define functions in XSLT, like this simple one that outputs a string.

```
<xsl:template name="dosomething">
  <xsl:text>A function that does something</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This function can be called via `<xsl:call-template name="dosomething">`.

`<xsl:apply-templates>` is a little different and in it is the real power of XSLT: It takes any number of XML nodes (whatever you define in the `select` attribute), processes each of them (not necessarily in any predefined order), somebody could say that apply-templates works like a loop, but this is not exactly the case, as the nodes may be processed in any order, even in parallel, and finds matching templates for them:

```
<!-- sample XML snippet -->
<xml>
  <foo /><bar /><baz />
</xml>

<!-- sample XSLT snippet -->
<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" /> <!-- three nodes selected here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo"> <!-- will be called once -->
  <xsl:text>foo element encountered</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*"> <!-- will be called twice -->
  <xsl:text>other element countered</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you give up a little control to the XSLT processor - not you decide where the program flow goes, but the processor does by finding the most appropriate match for the node it's currently processing.

If multiple templates can match a node, the one with the more specific match expression wins. If more than one matching template with the same specificity exist, the one declared last wins.

You can concentrate more on developing templates and need less time to do "plumbing". Your programs will become more powerful and modularized, less deeply nested and faster (as XSLT processors are optimized for template matching).

A concept to understand with XSLT is that of the "current node". With `<xsl:apply-templates>` the current node moves on with every iteration, whereas `<xsl:call-template>` does not change the current node. I.e. the `.` within a called template refers to the same node as the `.` in the calling template. This is not the case with apply-templates.

This is the basic difference. There are some other aspects of templates that affect their behavior: Their `mode` and `priority`, the fact that templates can have both a `name` and a `match`. It also has an impact whether the template has been imported (`<xsl:import>`) or not. These are advanced uses and you can deal with them when you get there.

Comment: @Tomalak: Good answer! However, the statement: "xsl:apply-templates is a loop" isn't correct. There is no indication in any official W3C spec that `<xsl:apply-templates>` must be implemented as a loop -- on the contrary, it *may* be implemented in parallel, because the different applications on the different nodes of the node-list are absolutely independent from each other.

Comment: @Dimitre: What I meant to say: From an end-user's perspective, `<xsl:apply-templates>` behaves like a loop. Implementation differences on the XSLT processor's end will not affect me as an XSLT programmer, the outcome is absolutely the same for parallelized and iterative implementations alike. But for an XSLT newbie with an imperative background, it helps to envision `<xsl:apply-templates>` as a kind of for-each loop, even if - technically - it isn't.

Comment: @Tomalak: While this may be useful for novice XSLT programmers, I think it is often misleading to them as they think that they can re-use state information accumulated in the "execution of the loop".

Comment: @Tomalak: Because of these facts, I think that it would be appropriate to modify "xsl:apply-templates is a loop"with somethinkg like: "xsl:apply-templates is *like* a loop"

Comment: @Tomalak: Loop is iteration, something `apply-templates` and `call-template` instructions are not for. They are the recursion mechanism in XSLT. And as Dimitre has answered, apply-templates is the polymorphism or data driven mechanism.

Comment: @Alejandro: Neither `apply-templates` nor `call-template` recurse on their own. Without *calling* them recursively, their effect is that of iteration.

Comment: @Tomalak: They might not recurse on their own, but there is no  recursion mechanism other than them.

Comment: @Tomalak - As user Ben points out in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15868300/1945651) (I'm posting this on his behalf because he can't post comments yet), the behavior of your XSLT here is not what you describe in the XML comments, or what I think you intended. `xml/*` has a higher template priority than `foo`, so what actually happens is that the third template is called three times and the second template isn't called at all.

Comment: @JLRishe Oh damn, this has been wrong all this time. Of course Ben is correct, I'll fix it immediately. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: > A concept to understand with XSLT is that of the "current node". With <xsl:apply-templates> the current node moves on with every iteration, whereas <xsl:call-template> does not change the current node. I.e. the . within a called template refers to the same node as the . in the calling template. This is not the case with apply-templates *** THANKS - This helped me a lot.

Comment: @Jan Nice to hear. That's one of the points easily missed by beginners, leading to complicated attempts to transfer context between different templates when in fact context is transferred automatically.

Answer (score 17):

To add to the good answer by @Tomalak:

**Here are some unmentioned and important differences**:

1. **`xsl:apply-templates` is much richer and deeper than `xsl:call-templates` and even from  `xsl:for-each`,** simply because we don't know what code will be applied on the nodes of
   the selection -- in the general case this code will be different for
   different nodes of the node-list.
2. **The code that will be applied
   can be written way after the `xsl:apply template`s was written** and by
   people that do not know the original author.

**The [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)'s implementation of higher-order functions (HOF) in XSLT wouldn't be possible** if XSLT didn't have the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction.

**Summary**: Templates and the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction is how XSLT implements and deals with polymorphism.

**Reference**: See this whole thread: **http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200411/msg00546.html**

Answer (score 11):

`xsl:apply-templates` is usually (but not necessarily) used to process all or a subset of children of the current node with *all* applicable templates. This supports the recursiveness of XSLT application which is matching the (possible) recursiveness of the processed XML.

`xsl:call-template` on the other hand is much more like a normal function call. You execute exactly one (named) template, usually with one or more parameters.

So I use `xsl:apply-templates` if I want to intercept the processing of an interesting node and (usually) inject something into the output stream. A typical (simplified) example would be

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

whereas with `xsl:call-template` I typically solve problems like adding the text of some subnodes together, transforming select nodesets into text or other nodesets and the like - anything you would write a specialized, reusable function for.

### Edit:

As an additional remark to your specific question text:

```
<xsl:call-template name="nodes"/>
```

This calls a template which is named 'nodes':

```
    <xsl:template name="nodes">...</xsl:template>
```

This is a different semantic than:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="nodes"/>
```

...which applies all templates to all children of your current XML node whose name is 'nodes'.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality is indeed similar (apart from the calling semantics, where `call-template` requires a `name` attribute and a corresponding names template).

However, the parser will not execute the same way.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256487.aspx):

> Unlike `<xsl:apply-templates>`, `<xsl:call-template>` does not change the current node or the current node-list.