# xsl unordered list with same node names

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to print each "string" node as a li item from the following xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.url.org/url/envelope/"
>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <MultiSpeakMsgHeader 
            Version="" UserID="" 
            Pwd="" AppName="xx" AppVersion="x" 
            Company="xxx" xmlns="http://www.url.org/Version_3.0"
        />
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetMethodsResponse xmlns="http://www.url.org/Version_3.0">
            <GetMethods>
                <string>GetDomainMembers</string>
                <string>GetDomainNames</string>
                <string>GetMethods</string>
                <string>pingURL</string>
                <string>GetAllMeters</string>
                <string>GetAllServiceLocations</string>
                <string>GetAllCustomers</string>
                <string>GetCustomerByCustId</string>
                <string>GetServiceLocationByAccountNo</string>
                <string>GetServiceLocationByMeterNo</string>
                <string>ReadingChangedNotification</string>
            </GetMethods>
        </GetMethodsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i currently have the following xsl code -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/GetMethods">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="GetMethods/string">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string"/><br/>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>    
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but all this does is prints each string node as a long line with no list formatting.  any help would be appreciated.

i want this simple output:

```
    <ul>
        <li>GetDomainMembers</li>
        <li>GetDomainNames</li>
        <li>GetMethods</li>
        <li>pingURL</li>
        <li>GetAllMeters</li>
        <li>GetAllServiceLocations</li>
        <li>GetAllCustomers</li>
        <li>GetCustomerByCustId</li>
        <li>GetServiceLocationByAccountNo</li>
        <li>GetServiceLocationByMeterNo</li>
        <li>ReadingChangedNotification</li>
    </ul>
```

i'm currently getting this output (there is no formatting):

```
                                          GetDomainMembers            GetDomainNames            GetMethods            pingURL            GetAllMeters            GetAllServiceLocations            GetAllCustomers            GetCustomerByCustId            GetServiceLocationByAccountNo            GetServiceLocationByMeterNo            ReadingChangedNotification
```

Comment: Please show the XML input you are actually using, and the output you are actually getting... your description of it is unclear, and there are multiple incompatibilities between both of them and the XSLT you showed. Are you using XSLT 2.0 and xpath-default-namespace? Please show your `<xsl:stylesheet>` start tag and its attributes and namespace declarations.

Comment: i've updated the code per your instructions - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:response="http://www.url.org/Version_3.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt response"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//response:GetMethods" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="response:GetMethods">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response:string" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="response:string">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- First we must make known the namespace that your response element is in. In your case the namespace URI is `http://www.url.org/Version_3.0`, which we need to assign to a prefix to make it usable in the XSLT. I chose to call that prefix `response`.
- Next we need to control the output of the XSLT. This is easiest by matching the root node (`<xsl:template match="/">`) and defining where to go next by directly selecting `//response:GetMethods` for processing.
- Templates for `response:GetMethods` and `response:string` define the rest of the transformation.
- Lastly we must make sure that XML namespace prefixes do not show up in the resulting HTML. That's what `exclude-result-prefixes` does.
- See it here: http://www.xmlplayground.com/kS1Cul
- You can also read [What are the differences between 'call-template' and 'apply-templates' in XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478045/18771) where I explained `<xsl:apply-templates>` a little closer.
- In general you should avoid writing `<xsl:for-each>` and choose `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead.

Comment: this solved the issue - thanks so much for the detailed response.  i definitely have some learning to do!

Answer (score 1):

There is no element in your given input matching the pattern `"/GetMethods"`. So your XML is probably being processed by the default template (though we don't know without seeing the rest of your XSLT). The default template outputs the text content of each element.

To fix this,

1. Your match pattern shouldn't start with `/`, since `GetMethods` is not the top-level element. If you meant `//GetMethods`, that will match a `<GetMethods>` element (in no namespace) that occurs anywhere. But so will the pattern `GetMethods`; the `//` at the beginning is redundant.
2. You need to specify the correct namespace for `GetMethods`. According to your input XML, `GetMethods` is in the namespace whose URI is `http://www.test.org/Version_3.0`. So you need to declare a namespace prefix for that namespace (e.g. "test") and use it in your match pattern:

_

```
 <xsl:template match="test:GetMethods"
      xmlns:test="http://www.test.org/Version_3.0">...
```

Actually it's probably more practical to move the namespace declaration (`xmlns:test="..."`) to the top-level `<xsl:stylesheet>` element (if you don't have it already). Then the `test` prefix will be available anywhere in the stylesheet that you need it.

Comment: i'm still not following where the xmlns:test="http://www.test.org/Version_3.0"> is supposed to go?

Comment: @user1822065: Best to put it on the outermost element, `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:test=...>`