# Can anyone show me the XSL to convert this XML to a HTML Table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml, html-table

I have been asked to convert a XML doc with an internal DTD and an external XSL into a neatly presented table with two sets of criteria - which I chose as two different authors.

TBH I don't even know if I have the XML & DTD doc right? And when it comes to using XPath and XSLT I have absolutely no idea what to do.
I'm hoping someone can show me the finished table so that I can work backwards from it and understand how you did it.

Here is my XML Doc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Batman.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE comics [
<!ELEMENT comics (name,author,publisher,country,year,prics)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
]>
<comics>
   <batman>
       <issue2>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Scott Synder</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue2>
       <issue3>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Scott Synder</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue3>
       <issue4>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Scott Synder</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue4>
       <issue5>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Scott Synder</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue5>
       <issue6>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Darren Darcer</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue6>
       <issue7>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Darren Darcer</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue7>
       <issue8>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Darren Darcer</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue8>
       <issue9>
           <name>Batman Eternal</name>
           <author>Darren Darcer</author>
           <publisher>DC Comics</publisher>
           <country>USA</country>
           <year>2012</year>
           <price>$2.99</price>
       </issue9>
    </batman>
</comics>
```

@Tomalak - as you can see I am not getting it...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="batman.xsl">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
      <th><td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Publisher</td><td>Country</td><td>Year</td><td>Price</td></th>
      <tr bgcolor="#ebebeb">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>author</th>
      <th>publisher</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>year</th>
      <th>price</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="comics/batman/issue">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you've spent 10 hours on this, surely you must have some XSLT code to show what you've tried?

Comment: yeah I didn't put any of my attempts up cause I kbnew they were garbage

Comment: Probably, yes. But if you've been struggling for 10 hours then you have a problem with the concept itself. And it's way easier to help setting your concept straight if we can see your code.

Comment: there u go that's the last attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML text is not valid for the specified DTD!

If specified DTD is wrong and XML text is right then this XSL makes HTML table:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>
  <xsl:template match="comics">
    <html>
      <head><link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></head>
      <body><xsl:apply-templates select="batman"/></body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="batman">
    <table>
      <th><td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Publisher</td><td>Country</td><td>Year</td><td>Price</td></th>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise, you can to modify this code easily, or me.

Comment: I still don't follow. I did the XML first then the DTD, I tried to use the DTD off another example. So if my XML is right what should the intergrated DTD be? And does that make the XSL you did need changing?

Comment: so I only need to use a wildcard for the whole table?

Comment: I forgot to mention it has to have the <xsl:choose> Element though
one author has to have a coloured background and the table needs a border. Whenevber I attempt to add one the whole table messes up?
So does the DTD still need altering? What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You were not that far off.

On a general note, XSLT is a programming language, do your indentation properly and consistently.

Also, you're shooting yourself in the foot with element names like `<batman>` or `<issue3>`. These elements should be called something like `<comic title="Batman">` and `<issue number="3">`. You should actually change that first in your XML. Never use variable element names.

Here's your attempt, annotated:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0"
>
  <!-- 
    Error: XHTML is XML, not HTML. Use method="xml", not "html".
  -->
  <xsl:output 
      method="html" 
      encoding="utf-8" 
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
  />

  <!-- 
    Error: You can't use "batman.xsl" here.
      You *already are* inside the XML file. Use match expressions
      to refer to specific nodes that the template should be used for.
  -->
  <xsl:template match="batman.xsl">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#ebebeb">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>author</th>
            <th>publisher</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
          <!--
            Common mistake: avoid <xsl:for-each>
              XSLT is a template-matching language. You should 
              write templates.
          -->
          <xsl:for-each select="comics/batman/issue">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="author" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="country" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="price" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A better approach (needs all your `<issueX>` elements replaced with `<issue>`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
  <xsl:output 
      method="xml" 
      encoding="utf-8"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
  />

  <!-- create the base output document -->
  <xsl:template match="/comics">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Comic List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Comics</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- any children of the "comics" element get a table -->
  <xsl:template match="comics/*">
    <table border="1">
      <caption><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Publisher</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="issue" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- any issue becomes a table row -->
  <xsl:template match="issue">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="author" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="publisher" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="country" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="year" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="price" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- 
    We don't need to specify a template for <name>, <author>, etc
    because XSLT defaults to "if there's no template defined, copy 
    the text to the output - which is what we want.
    But *if* you want to make the <name> bold, for example,
    all you need to do is create a <xsl:template match="name">.
  -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand `<xsl:apply-templates>` you might want to read this first: [What are the differences between 'call-template' and 'apply-templates' in XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478045/what-are-the-difference-between-call-template-and-apply-templates-in-xsl)

The advantages of breaking up your program into templates are:

- Smaller templates. You can see what's going on in a template without scrolling.
- Less nesting makes the code easier to read.
- Higher re-usability: You can write templates that work for several different inputs and 
  don't have to copy/paste portions of your code.
- No need for any loops.
- You get to use the mechanism behind XSLT's default template rules (read about them) and match specificity: You can define default behavior and override it with special behavior without even writing a single `if`.

Comment: Thankyou for your help @Tomalak but it is still as clear as mud to me. I just can't grasp the process. I think I will ask my tutor. I thought that my course would teach me html before this stuff but they expect us to know how to write code without a single lesson and it's very hard to understand the theory. Thanks again.

Comment: @jimbojones If you're just beginning to learn about HTML then XSLT is way out out of scope IMHO.