# calling custom template from xsl:if block

Tags: xslt-1.0

can we call custom template from inside xsl:if block in xslt 1.0 as I have done below..
i have called a custom template named abcCodetemplate as shown below from inside xsl:if block please advise is it correct approach..

```
<xsl:if test="$TSS='true'">
          <xsl:variable name="abcCode">
          <xsl:call-template name="abcCodetemplate">
          <xsl:with-param name="Var" select="/ase/*/rty"/> 
           </xsl:call-template> 
         </xsl:variable>

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a correct approach. But if it's possible use `<xsl:apply-template>` 
take a look here [What are the differences between 'call-template' and 'apply-templates' in XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478045/what-are-the-difference-between-call-template-and-apply-templates-in-xsl)