# XSLT read Table of contents from docx document.xml

Tags: xslt, docx, tableofcontents

I am trying to retrieve the TOC from docx's document.xml file using XSLT

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" exclude-result-prefixes="w" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="w:sdt">
        <xsl:element name="root">

          <xsl:attribute name="label">
            <xsl:value-of select="w:sdtPr/w:docPartObj/w:docPartGallery/@w:val"/>
          </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:for-each select="w:sdtContent/w:p">
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val">

              <xsl:element name="sec">

                <xsl:attribute name="label">
                  <xsl:value-of select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="anchor">
                  <xsl:value-of select="w:hyperlink/@w:anchor"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                  <xsl:value-of select="w:hyperlink/w:r/w:t"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

              </xsl:element>

            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

i am getting the desired result but with additional w:p tag values outside of w:sdtContent scope.

I am a beginner in XSLT and not sure what i am doing wrong here.

(if the source xml would help, please let me know i will post it here.)

Comment: Your XSLT is syntactically invalid. Please fix that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT processes its input, starting from the root node, with [a set of default rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378562/18771). These default rules can be overridden - but you don't do that. I suspect the unwanted extra output you see comes from the default rules.

Your stylesheet contains a template `<xsl:template match="w:sdt">` and the XSLT processor *does* run that template, but only when it gets to a `<w:sdt>` while it traverses the input document.

If you want to start at the root node yourself and *dictate* what nodes the XSLT processor should look at, override the default behavior by writing a template that matches the root node (`<xsl:template match="/">`).

```
<xsl:transform
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  exclude-result-prefixes="w"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-temmplates select="//w:sdt" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:sdt">
    <root label="{w:sdtPr/w:docPartObj/w:docPartGallery/@w:val}" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:sdtContent/w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val]" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:sdtContent/w:p">
    <sec 
      label="{w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val}"
      anchor="{w:hyperlink/@w:anchor}"
      title="{w:hyperlink/w:r/w:t}"
    />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Other notes:

- Don't write `<xsl:element name="foo">`. Write `<foo>`.
- Don't write `<xsl:attribute name="bar">` Write `<foo bar="{xpath-expr}">`.
- Avoid `<xsl:for-each>`. Use `<xsl:apply-templates>` and `<xsl:template>`.
- Avoid `<xsl:if>` for filtering which nodes you want to process. Write an appropriate XPath expression that only selects nodes you want to process instead.
- Possibily helpful reading: [How `<xsl:apply-templates>` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478126/18771).

Comment: Tomalak, Thank you very much for the explanations and the code. Also thanks for the very useful links.