# Using apply-template instead of call-template

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to replace the call-template statement in the following [stylesheet](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/10) with a apply-statement? So that the structure of the templates are nearly the same. With structure I mean that I have a xpath to select a element form the source xml e.g. `/shiporder/address/city` and I have a target xpath for my output xml e.g. `/root/Address/Country` then I step reverse through the source path. All `/shiporder/address/city` goes under `Country` all `/shiporder/address` goes under `Address` and the root `shiporder` become the tag `root`.

Source XML:

```
<shiporder>
  <shipto>orderperson1</shipto>
  <shipfrom>orderperson2</shipfrom>
  <address>
  <city>London</city>
  </address>
  <address>
  <city>Berlin</city>
  </address>
</shiporder>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shiporder"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="address/city"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Identity" />
    </root>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="Identity">
    <Identity>
        <xsl:call-template name="Name" />
    </Identity>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Name">
    <Name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder/shipto"/>
    </Name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto">
    <Last>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </Last>
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="/shiporder/address/city">
    <Country>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </Country>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you chose to use `<xsl:call-template>` in the first place?

Comment: I don't get your question. I want to use apply instead of call.

Comment: I know. I want to understand why you used "call", so that maybe I can help to clarify a mistake in your thinking.

Comment: Because I had no better idea to define a template where I can write a node to the output and apply the next template and pass through the current node to that output without using the `mode` attribute.

Comment: Ah. Well, you can output nodes with any kind of nesting in any kind of template. No need to start new templates per nesting level or anything like that. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/4478045/18771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `<xsl:call-template name="..."/>` can be turned into a `<xsl:apply-templates select="current()" mode="..."/>` and `<xsl:template match="node()" mode="..."/>` (as long as this mode is not used anywhere else).

But there, the upvoted answer is way more suited.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="address/city"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="shipto"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="shipto">
        <Identity>
            <Name>
                <Last><xsl:value-of select="."/></Last>
            </Name>
        </Identity>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder/address/city">
        <Country>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Country>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I also had this solution in mind, but that is not an option, because the `Identity` template could look like `<xsl:template name="Identity">
    <Identity>
        <xsl:call-template name="Name" />
        <xsl:apply-template select="foo" />         
   </Identity>
</xsl:template>`