# How to keep HTML content during XSL transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

As part of a larger XML I have elements like `<testdata>abc</testdata>` and this String `abc` gets nicely put into a table cell `<td>abc</td>` using the following fragment in an XSLT file...

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="testdata"/></td>
```

Now what if the test data itself is HTML like this?

```
<testdata>
    <ol>
        <li>abc</li>
        <li>xyz</li>
    </ol>
</testdata>
```

Can I somehow enhance the above `<xsl:value-of/>` to take the whole content of the `<testdata>` element as it is? I keep losing the HTML formatting, resulting in `<td>abcxyz</td>`, but what I would expect is this:

```
<td>
    <ol>
        <li>abc</li>
        <li>xyz</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

**PS:**

In some other related questions I found this xsl template as a solution. But I don't understand how I can apply such an identity copy to only the contents of my `<testdata>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow enhance the above `<xsl:value-of/>` to take the whole
>   content of the `<testdata>` element as it is?

Yes, you can change it to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="testdata/node()"/>
```

You would not normally use the *identity transform* template in a document that outputs HTML, unless your input is HTML too.

Comment: And HTML is not XML. Only XHTML is XML.

Comment: @ceving No, not only XHTML is XML. Anyway, this is irrelevant to the issue being discussed here.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

This template outputs `<td>` for each `<testdata>` element and then instructs the XSLT processor to do whatever is necessary to the contents.

```
<xsl:template match="testdata">
  <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

If the identity template you mentioned is defined in your XSLT code and no other templates match any of the content of `<testdata>`, it will be copied as-is.

If your XSLT code is one huge templates with a lot of `<xsl:for-each>` (most beginner's XSLT code looks like that), then you will have to rewrite it a bit to use template matching efficiently (also [see an explanation of template matching from an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478045/what-are-the-differences-between-call-template-and-apply-templates-in-xsl)).

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this before, but because `<testdata>` is matched in the context of its parent node, this XSLT instruction also copies over the sibling elements of `<testdata>`. Is there a way to narrow down the `select="node() | @*"` to something like `select="testdata/node() | @*"`

Comment: That's already what happens. Any `select` expression in XSLT works relative to the current context node. Inside an `<xsl:template match="foo">` that's the respective `<foo>` element. What you actually need is an `<xsl:apply-templates select="testdata" />` somewhere else. (Unless you opt for calling `<xsl:copy-of>`, like @michael.hor257k suggests. Then you don't need the identity template at all.)