# xslt call template not behaving as I expect

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

What concept am I missing that I'm not getting what I'm expecting? Also, why would @field be blank (not showing 'location') when matching the 2nd time around?

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <!-- sample XSLT snippet -->
  <xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    <!-- three nodes selected here -->
    <xsl:call-template name="rshandle" />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <!-- will be called once -->
    <xsl:text>
      foo element encountered
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- will be called twice -->
    <xsl:text>
      other element ecountered
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="rshandle" match="foo">
    <!-- will be called once -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@field" />
    <xsl:text>
      oops i did it again!
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="calltemplatematch.xslt"?>
<!-- sample XML snippet -->
<xml>
  <foo field="location"/>
  <bar />
  <baz />
</xml>
```

**expecting**

```
      other element ecountered

      other element ecountered

location
      oops i did it again!
```

**actual**

```
location
      oops i did it again!

      other element ecountered

      other element ecountered

      oops i did it again!
```

Comment: Which part do you need to be explained?

Comment: I updated OP, to be a little more specific. I guess for starters, why is @field blank (instead of showing location string) on the second instance that appears at the bottom?

Comment: I am afraid you'll need to pose a specific question for each item you don't understand.

Comment: No worries, will do

Comment: Note that you have two templates matching "foo" which is considered an error (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict). If the XSLT processor is not signalling the error it will pick the last matching template in the stylesheet. So, the template that outputs "foo element encountered" will not get used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet your expectations, the XSL should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!-- sample XSLT snippet -->
    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <!-- three nodes selected here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="foo" mode="rshandle"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- will be called twice -->
        <xsl:text>other element ecountered</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo" mode="rshandle">
        <!-- will be called once -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@field"/>
        <xsl:text>oops i did it again!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Also, why would @field be blank (not showing 'location') when matching the 2nd time around?

Because you used [`<xsl:call-template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/call-template). The good explanation from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478126/2570353):

> A concept to understand with XSLT is that of the "current node". With `<xsl:apply-templates>` the current node moves on with every iteration, whereas `<xsl:call-template>` does not change the current node. I.e. the `.` within a called template refers to the same node as the `.` in the calling template. This is not the case with apply-templates.

Answer (score 1):

> why is @field blank on the second instance that appears at the bottom?

Because when the "rshandle" template is **called**, it is called from the context of the `xml` root element - which does not have a `field` attribute. *Calling* a template does not change the current context - unlike *applying* templates.