How to accomplish this transformation without using multiple <for-each> loops
Im having an issue coming up with a strategy for this transformation.  I cant use a single for-each because the resulting XML must be sequenced.
Here is the input xml
 <people>
    <person>
        <name>Tim</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jon</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Sam</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Bill</name>
    </person>
</people>

Here is how it needs to output
<people>
    <friend>
        <name>Jon</name>
    </friend>
    <friend>
        <name>Bill</name>
    </friend>
    
    <foe>
        <name>Sam</name>
    </foe>
    
    <neutral>
        <name>Tim</name>
    </neutral>
    <neutral>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </neutral>
</people>

The criteria for placing each name as friend, foe, neutral is in the xslt, but if I loop through each name, the elements friend, foe, and neutral will be out of order and fail schema tests.  This is in XSLT 2.0

Without knowing what are "the criteria for placing each name as friend, foe, neutral" it is not possible to address your question. I am also not sure what is the problem with using multiple xsl:for-each instructions, if that is what the logic of the transformation requires. (BTW, xsl:for-each is not a "loop".)

@michael.hor257k - I was hoping there would be a more performant solution then looping over the same set multiple times calling the same function, which to answer the first part of the question, is the criteria.  plug the name into a function and it returns friend, neutral, or foe.  I could loop over the source 3 times. loop 1 ask if each name is friend, then output.  loop 2 ask if each name is foe and then output....

@michael.hor257k as for for-each not being a loop, i dont know, i see stuff like this all the time
https://support.claris.com/s/article/Looping-in-XSLT-1503692927412?language=en_US#:~:text=XSLT%20has%20the%20built%2Din,%3Afor%2Deach%3E%20tag.
seems like some people call it a loop

Lots of people call it a loop, because they don't know any better (esp. the people writing documentation for Claris). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70034109/3016153. As for the logic of the transformation, it is not getting any clearer.

This is really impossible to understand. Does your XSLT have a list of names in each category, or what?

@y.arazim Im trying to simplify the logic.  just assume that there is a function called "FriendOrFoe" that takes name as a param.  you pass in a name and it tells you friend, foe, neutral

@michael.hor257k Id be one of those people that dont know any better.  Im just sitting here on my 4th of july looking for a little help. I dont know xslt well but am trying to write some.

But there is no such function. I f you want to get a reasonable answer, ask a reasonable question. Especially if you are looking for an efficient answer.

BTW, if there were such function, you could simply sort or group the people by its value. But that's just shooting the breeze.

Personally, I see nothing wrong in referring to iteration statements like xsl:for-each as 'loop' constructs. Although the word "loop" is not a keyword in the XSLT language, there are several language constructs which produce what are colloquially called "loops" (including in the XSLT specifications themselves).

@ConalTuohy Have you read the linked answer?

I did read your previous answer but I didn't find it convincing. I just don't think it's helpful to tell people off for using the word "loop" in connection with xsl:for-each which is quite plainly a looping construct.

Well, the fact is that it is not a loop. I don't think pointing out a misconception is "telling people off". Sounds more like something you are trying to do here.

It's common to see the language of "loops" used in reference to the xsl:for-each statement. It even appears in the official XSLT specification. Perhaps your opinion is that they should not be called "loops" because each iteration is computationally independent of the other iterations, and they could potentially be executed non-sequentially. But that's rather an idiosyncratic opinion of what constitutes a "loop"; I don't think most people consider that a necessary characteristic of a "loop". I think it's pedantic and even quixotic to try to insist on that point in your answers.

"It even appears in the official XSLT specification." It most certainly does not. Get your facts straight before you attempt to lecture me. And I am also not interested in your characterization of my opinions and actions.

"For example, consider a function call that appears within an xsl:for-each instruction, where the supplied arguments to the function do not depend on the context item or on any variables declared within the xsl:for-each instruction. A possible optimization is to execute the function call only once, rather than executing it repeatedly each time round the loop (this is sometimes called loop-lifting)." https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/

I don't want to belabour the question of whether "loop" is the best term, though. The point I'm making is that it's not actually helpful to say that it's "wrong". If you want to point out that xsl:for-each has some distinct features from loops in some other languages, you can do that explicitly, in a way that actually conveys what those differences are, and why they may be relevant to the question being asked. Whereas stating they are "not loops" leaves it as a terminological quibble, and moreover it's confusing and unconvincing because it's one where actual usage is not on your side.

Nowhere in the section describing the xsl:for-each instruction is the word "loop" used. Now for the last time, please stop bothering me with your pontifications. If you have a problem with what I post, flag it for a moderator's attention.

Rather than flag misleading comments for moderation I generally prefer to just post a counterpoint, but I'll bear your suggestion in mind


just assume that there is a function called "FriendOrFoe" that takes name as a param. you pass in a name and it tells you friend, foe, neutral

Just to show how absurd your request is, let's pretend that such function does exist. In such case this stylesheet would produce the exact result you show:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myfunc="http://www.example.com/myfunc" exclude-result-prefixes="myfunc">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="person" group-by="myfunc:FriendOrFoe(name)">
            <xsl:sort select="index-of(('friend', 'foe', 'neutral'), current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="myfunc:FriendOrFoe">
    <xsl:param name="name"/> 
    <!-- ??? -->
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Or maybe even better:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myfunc="http://www.example.com/myfunc" exclude-result-prefixes="myfunc">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kRole" match="person" use="myfunc:FriendOrFoe(name)" />

<xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:variable name="people" select="." />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="('friend', 'foe', 'neutral')" >
            <xsl:variable name="role" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('kRole', $role, $people)">
                <xsl:element name="{$role}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="myfunc:FriendOrFoe">
    <xsl:param name="name"/> 
    <!-- ??? -->
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>


This seems like a reasonable solution, to me. I'm not sure why you'd say the request is 'absurd', though?

An alternative approach could be to transform the sequence of person elements into friend, foe, and neutral elements in a first pass, and then to output three subsequences in the desired order.
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:friends="http://www.example.com/friends" exclude-result-prefixes="friends">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="classified-persons">
         <xsl:for-each select="person">
            <xsl:element name="{friends:classify-name(name)}">
               <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:copy-of select="
        (
          $classified-persons/friend,
          $classified-persons/foe,
          $classified-persons/neutral
        )
      "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="friends:classify-name">
      <xsl:param name="name"/> 
      <xsl:sequence select="
        if ($name = ('John', 'Bill')) then 
          'friend'
        else if ($name = ('Sam')) then
          'foe'
        else
          'neutral'
      "/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>


OP complained about having to "loop over the source 3 times". This does it 4 times:  once by the person's name, and 3 times by the assigned element's name.

The code in my answer does effectively traverse the same list 4 times, but it only calls the name-classification function in the first traversal, so it addresses what I took to be the OP's concern to minimise calls to that function (my assumption was that this function might be quite slow, potentially involving some external lookup)
